# How to send F1, F2, F3... keypresses with phpseclib via ssh shell

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($address, $port);
if (!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo "<pre>";

$ssh->setTimeout(5);
echo $ssh->read();
$ssh->write($app_name);
$ssh->write("\n \n \n b");
$ssh->write($f_one); // This is where I need to hit F1
echo $ssh->read();
```

I've searched and found chr() might be my solution but the decial character code for the function keys includes a comma (is a pair: 00,59) which chr() splits as separate arguments and fails.

This is where I found the decimal pair, if it's correct.
http://www.jimprice.com/jim-asc.shtml#keycodes

Following a post in this thread.
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t277457-re-ascii-code-for-functions-keys-f1-f12-and-tab-key.html

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the second link, did you do some research into the apparent mapping for the function keys?

Comment: The second link is meaningless nonsense. The "ASCII" codes it claims for function keys are within the lower case alphabetic range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key code list you're looking at is talking about keyboard scan codes, which are something completely different and unrelated.

The VT100 sequences for function keys are... complicated. F1 through F4 are typically sent as:

```
F1: \x1bOP
F2: \x1bOQ
F3: \x1bOR
F4: \x1bOS
```

However, this pattern does **not** hold for subsequent function keys. For a more complete list, see http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html (search for "12 function keys", note that `CSI` represents the sequence `\x1b[`.)

Comment: I tried running the script where $f_one = "\x1b[OP but the program replied that it received the O and P as individual key presses. Should I be using chr("\X1b[OP") ?

Comment: My mistake -- I was specifying the sequences wrong. Remove the `[` and try again.

Comment: Same result. I tried escaping the forward slash as well. I was afraid in PHP "\x1bOP" would evaluate as the string "1bOP". Still no luck.

Comment: The sequence should be three characters - `\x1b` is an escape for the ESC character. You do not need to use `chr()`.

Comment: Got it! You've been very helpful. Your solution works great. Sorry I don't have enough rep to vote it up.